# Xpages "Views" with beans: Categorize, Sort, Search

Tags: java, xpages, javabeans, xpages-extlib

I'm trying to do the OOP approach in all my xPages. As expected I'm facing several issues, but also have tons of advantages doing so.
My question is related to Views (Repeat controls). I am loading a `List<myCustomBean>` for my repeat controls that contains all available objects of type `myCustomBean` and display each `myCustomBean` the way I want in a Bootstrap table row. That works all fine.

I'm able to sort my List with URL parameter `sortedBy=MySortColumn` with my own method. - Problem 1 solved.

How would I approach a Categorization in my Repeat Control? So I could easily sort the beans by the Cotegory, but how would I display it, incl. expandable and collapsible twisties? Maybe there is a Custom control that I can use? Or a Control of the Extension Library?

Or do I have to build everything from scratch myself?

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The Data View control is probably the best. Like the View Panel or Data View, it's a extension of the Repeat Control. But it has much more flexibility that the View Panel and allows much more configurable layout than the Data View. It has a `categoryColumn` property, but that's designed for binding to a dominoView datasource. But there is also the `categoryRow` facet which can be used.

Essentially, using a `dominoView` component is already using OOP programming. Your repeat is using `List<myCustomBean>`, dominoView returns `List<DominoViewEntry>`. Properties on the `dominoView` are used to interrogate the underlying `View` object within the database and return only those `ViewEntry` objects from the `ViewNavigator` or `ViewEntryCollection` that are required. It wraps the `ViewEntry` as a `DominoViewEntry` object for just a selection of those, based on the `rows` property of whatever uses the `DominoView`.

As someone who built a subset of that functionality for use from Vaadin (see my XPages to Web App blog series http://www.intec.co.uk/tag/xpages-to-web-app-tutorial/), within XPages I typipcally use the `dominoView` object unless I'm extracting a small subset of ViewEntries / Documents. When I use ViewEntryCollection / DocumentCollection, I rarely wrap, preferring to let XPages optimise retrieval rather than re-develop that optimisation myself.